# How to layout a view with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints enabled

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios14

As I understand it, there is a new method to configure UITableView cells for iOS 14. I am using this method, but when I implemented it, there was an error.

`Exception  NSException *   "The content view returned from the content configuration must have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints enabled"`

However, when I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true, I could no longer layout the view for the cell. That is, even though I was setting the view's width, nothing was displayed.

Below is the method I am using (without my code that configures the views). My question is whether there is a way to avoid the error while still being able to layout the view.

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
extension GoalCell {

    struct Configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
        
        func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
            return MyContentView(configuration: self)
        }
        func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> GoalCell.Configuration {
            return self
        }
    }
    
    class MyContentView: UIView, UIContentView {
        var configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
            didSet {
                self.configure()
            }
        }
        }()
        init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
            self.configuration = configuration
            super.init(frame: .zero)
            
            self.configure()
        }
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        private func configure() {
            guard let config = self.configuration as? Configuration else { return }
            
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see labels or anything being used to display the content.